# Показать хинт на мобильном устройстве

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Берем js-api карт версии 2.1.
[Песочница.](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/balloon_and_hint)
При тапе на точку показывается балун. А как на мобильном устройстве показать хинт?